# Recurrence Relation Time Complexity Linear

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence

I'm trying to understand how to find the asymptotic complexity of a linear recurrence relation. So far, what I understand is that if only one linear recurrence call is made **(ex. cn + T(n-4))**, substitution or the recurrence tree can be used.

However, what should one do if there are 2 or more linear recurrence calls?

For the example I got in class (shown below), I got that **T(n) = T(n-4) + logn + T(n-10)**. I tried setting a lower bound of **T(n)> log n + 2T(n-10)** since that's how we solved Fibbonacci Numbers, but I wound up with a complex summation that I could not solve.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: There are many ways to solve recurrences like these. MIT’s intro discrete math course has a bunch of great examples about how to do this. Look up the “annihilator method” for one such approach.